# Getting a value out of a hash

Tags: ruby, jruby, trinidad-gem

I'm using the gem `twitter_oauth`. I put in the tokens, and I get my `access_token`. Now I want to access some information in this hash, but it won't let me for some reason. The best I can do is inspect it:

```
access_token.inspect #=>
#<OAuth::AccessToken:0x72ca83b2 @params={:oauth_token=>"token (filtered of course)", "oauth_token"=>"token", :oauth_token_secret=>"secret", "oauth_token_secret"=>"secret", :user_id=>"id", "user_id"=>"id", :screen_name=>"Imnotanerd", "screen_name"=>"Imnotanerd"}, @response=#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>, @consumer=#<OAuth::Consumer:0x6bb7645d @http_method=:post, @options={:signature_method=>"HMAC-SHA1", :request_token_path=>"/oauth/request_token", :authorize_path=>"/oauth/authenticate", :access_token_path=>"/oauth/access_token", :proxy=>nil, :scheme=>:header, :http_method=>:post, :oauth_version=>"1.0", :site=>"http://api.twitter.com", :request_endpoint=>nil}, @secret="secret", @http=#<Net::HTTP api.twitter.com:80 open=false>, @uri=#<URI::HTTP:0x384bc24e URL:http://api.twitter.com>, @key="key">, @token="token", @secret="secret">
```

I tried to access the values like so:

```
access_token[params]["user_id"] #gave up on this due to me reasoning that it's confusing params with the routing variable, params
access_token["params"]["user_id"]
access_token["consumer"]["secret"]
```

And all of these resulted in an Internal Server Error. No other information was given when the error was reported.

I'm using JRuby 1.7 RC2, and the latest Trinidad web server. I have also tried this in WEBrick too, and the same error appears.

Comment: try `access_token[:user_id]` or `access_token[params][:user_id]`

Comment: both result in an Internal Server Error

Comment: how about `access_token.params[:user_id]`?

Comment: oh my. That worked! I have to make a note to my self that a @var in a hash can be reached like a class variable. You could put that as an answer, and I'll accept it!

Comment: it's not a hash, `params` is instance variable, not class variable, and can only be reached this way if you have accessor defined (which is defined in `ConsumerToken` btw https://github.com/oauth/oauth-ruby/blob/master/lib/oauth/tokens/consumer_token.rb)

Comment: I was saying that access_token was a hash, not params. And now I see I was wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since it's been several months, I'm just adding the official answer that @ionut-hulub answered above so this already answered question stops showing up with no answer.

```
access_token.params[:user_id]
```